# compare the value and print

Tags: python

I want to read out certain lines from this ASCII file below, and save it to another file. for an example I want to read out the rows started from column 2 which has value 17. If column 2 has value 17, then only that row goes to the output file.

So far I have a code below,

```
import numpy as np
datafilename = 'pol_17.txt'
g = np.genfromtxt(datafilename, skiprows=6, usecols=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7),delimiter=None, dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8')])
if g['f0']==17:
    print[g]
```

In the output, I am getting "ValueError:" from python.

The input file format is as below.

```
# Energy  = 4.92758E+03 
# ESigma  = 2.80000E+00 
# ETrans  = 3.78310E+02 
# Density = 1.00000E+00 
# IDR     = -1 

  7    16     0 -1  6.49729E+03  5.59241E-04  1.177E+00  4.511E-01
  7    16     1 -1  6.47947E+03  4.05646E-05  1.177E+00  4.511E-01
  7    17     0 -1  6.50710E+03  7.44345E-02  8.230E-01 -6.451E-01
  7    17     1 -1  6.48929E+03  2.11547E-03  8.230E-01 -6.451E-01
  7    17     2 -1  6.48454E+03  3.67490E-03  1.044E+00  1.271E-01
  7    17     3 -1  6.47442E+03  8.22948E-05  1.221E+00  5.434E-01
  7    18     3 -1  6.47664E+03  3.25040E-03  1.000E+00  0.000E+00
  7    18     4 -1  6.46889E+03  4.90487E-04  1.000E+00  0.000E+00
  7    18    13 -1  6.26433E+03  2.38729E-05  1.000E+00  0.000E+00
  7    18    14 -1  6.25109E+03  5.84543E-06  1.000E+00  0.000E+00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be:

```
np.savetxt(outputfilename, g[g['f0'] == 17], fmt='%d %d %d %E% E %E %E')
```

where `outputfilename` is set to the appropriate output file name. If I were to name that file `test2.dat`, I get:

```
> cat test2.dat
17 0 -1 6.507100E+03 7.443450E-02 8.230000E-01 -6.451000E-01
17 1 -1 6.489290E+03 2.115470E-03 8.230000E-01 -6.451000E-01
17 2 -1 6.484540E+03 3.674900E-03 1.044000E+00 1.271000E-01
17 3 -1 6.474420E+03 8.229480E-05 1.221000E+00 5.434000E-01
```

The format string can be modified to get a particular spacing/precision in the file.

Comment: To understand how this works and why the OP method doesn't, do `print g['f0']==17` and next `print g[g['f0']==17]`

Comment: I have more files like above with different values. for an example, file 'pol_17.txt' has number 17, and useful rows in the files are also starting from 17. And there are more files range from 17 to 52, have same format. So I want to make a loop, where it takes only useful rows from each files and then save it to the main file.
I have small working program for it, But it takes rows as a string. I want it in a format. The program is in a second comment.

Comment: `txtfile1 = open("output_pol.txt", 'w')`  
`for dec in range(17,53):`  
    `gname = os.path.normpath('/home/data_%s/pol_%d.txt'%state,dec))`  
    `g = np.genfromtxt(gname, skiprows=7, usecols=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),delimiter=None, dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8')])`  
    `for pol, num in enumerate(g['f0']):`  
        `if num == dec:`  
            `print g[pol]`  
            `txtfile1.write(str(g[pol]))`  
            `txtfile1.write('\n')`  
`txtfile1.close()`

Comment: sorry for above. I am not aware, how to format text as a code.

Comment: If you want to write the rows out line-by-line with a particular format, you should take a look at the python format specification mini-language: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that g['f0'] isn't an entry in the column, it's the entire column.

```
print g['f0'] #outputs [16 16 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18]
```

We can write a pretty simple program to output each row however:

```
for idx, num in enumerate(g['f0']):
    if num == 17:
        print g[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to iterate over the rows:

```
for row in g:
    if row['f0'] == 17:
        print row
```

Answer (score 0):

`g['f0'] == 17` does an element-wise comparison, as `g['f0']` is an array

```
>>> g['f0']
array([16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18])
>>> g['f0'] == 17
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So we have an array of booleans for the rows of `g`. If we tried to evaluate this to a boolean (this happens in the if statement):

```
>>> bool(g['f0'] == 17)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This does not work, as this operation does not make sense either. But we can use the boolean array as index for the array as whole, to get only the rows, where `g['f0']==17` by doing:

```
>>> g[g['f0'] == 17]
array([ (17, 0, -1, 6507.1000000000004, 0.074434500000000001, 0.82299999999999995, -0.64510000000000001),
       (17, 1, -1, 6489.29, 0.0021154699999999999, 0.82299999999999995, -0.64510000000000001),
       (17, 2, -1, 6484.54, 0.0036749, 1.044, 0.12709999999999999),
       (17, 3, -1, 6474.4200000000001, 8.2294799999999997e-05, 1.2210000000000001, 0.54339999999999999)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8')])
```

You can also use `np.take`, it's a bit faster, but nearly equivalent to the indexing method, which is easier to read. To save it, you can do (stolen from @JoshAdel):

```
np.savetxt(outputfilename, g[g['f0'] == 17], fmt='%d %d %d %E% E %E %E')
```